# Create non-principal filter contained in a principal ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Please, consruct a non-principal filter $\mathscr F$, which is contained in a principal ultrafilter $\mathscr G$.

Comment: what do you mean by create? What does substantive mean? What does chief mean? Is non-chief the same as substantive? Are these filters on sets? Is this over any set? Over an infinite set? What does $F,\exists G,F\subseteq G,G$ mean?

Comment: This was closed far too hastily. *Chief* and *substantive* are pretty clearly mistranslations of some word whose meaning in this context is *principal*. The question almost certainly asks us to construct a non-principal filter $\mathscr{F}$ that can be extended to a principal ultrafilter $\mathscr{G}$.

Comment: Mariya: Let $E=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and let $\mathscr{F}=\{F\subseteq\Bbb N:F\supseteq E\}$; clearly $\mathscr{F}$ is a principal filter on $\Bbb N$. Let $\mathscr\{U\}$ be any non-principal ultrafilter on $E$, and let $\mathscr{G}=\{U\cup A:U\in\mathscr{U}\text{ and }A\subseteq\Bbb N\setminus E\}$: $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{G}$, and $\mathscr{G}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've reopened the question if you want to make that into an answer.

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks, and thanks for the ping.

Comment: Unfortunately, my previous comment does the opposite of what was requested!

Comment: Take as $F$ the set of all cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that contain $1$. These form a non-principal filter. But the principal ultrafilter generated by $1$ contains $F$.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming for this answer that you translated as *substantive* and *chief* some word whose correct English translation in this context is *principal*.

Let $E=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, let $\mathscr{U}$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N\setminus E$, and let $$\mathscr{F}=\{E\cup U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}\;;$$ then $\bigcap\mathscr{F}=E$, but $E\notin\mathscr{F}$, so $\mathscr{F}$ is non-principal. However, it’s easy to extend $\mathscr{F}$ to a non-principal filter $\mathscr{G}$ on $\Bbb N$: if $\mathscr{V}$ is any non-principal filter on $E$, $\mathscr{V}$ is a base for such a $\mathscr{G}$.